# Firestore many to many relationships - How to update data?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Like a note app, you can set tags to a note. Also, you can search notes with tag.
Here is the firestore structure:

```
notes(collection)
    note_1(doc)
        content: 'some words...'
        tags: ['apple', 'banana']

tags(collection)
    tag_1(doc)
        name: 'apple'
    tag_2(doc)
        name: 'banana'
```

If I change tag_1.name to 'new_apple', how shold I update note_1.tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to:

1. Query for all notes documents where the tags array contains "apple"
2. Iterate the documents in the result set. For each document:

   1. Update update the tags array in memory to remove "apple" and add "new_apple"
   2. Write the new tags array back to the document

Comment: Do this on the client side？Is this the best structure to achieve many to many relationships?

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you do this.  Your choice.  There are lots of ways to model data, and there is no "best" solution.  There are just upsides and downsides to consider.  Again, up to you to choose.